# 64 bit ASCII weaving

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, base-conversion, tiling

#### Input

Two integers:

- A non-negative integer ***W*** in the range 0 to 2^64-1, specifying the weave.
- A positive integer ***S*** in the range 1 to 255, specifying the side length.

These can be taken in whichever order suits you.

#### Output

An ***S*** by ***S*** ASCII representation of the requested weave (***S*** newline separated strings of ***S*** characters with an optional trailing newline). The weave is defined by the weave number ***W*** as follows:

Convert ***W*** to binary and split into 8 bytes. The first (most significant) byte defines the top row, from left (most significant bit) to right. The next byte defines the next row, and so on for 8 rows. The weave number defines an 8 by 8 square which should be tiled over the required area starting from the top left. That is, its top left corner should correspond to the top left corner of the area to be covered.

Every `0` should be displayed as a `|` and every `1` should be displayed as a `-`

#### Examples

Input: `0 8`

Ouput:

```
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
```

---

Input: `3703872701923249305 8`

Output:

```
||--||--
|--||--|
--||--||
-||--||-
||--||--
|--||--|
--||--||
-||--||-
```

---

Input: `3732582711467756595 10`

Output:

```
||--||--||
--||--||--
--||--||--
||--||--||
||--||--||
--||--||--
--||--||--
||--||--||
||--||--||
--||--||--
```

---

Input: `16141147355100479488 3`

Output:

```
---
|||
---
```

---

## Leaderboard Snippet

*(using [Martin's template](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/leaderboard-snippet))*

```js
var QUESTION_ID=54123;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),e.has_more?getAnswers():process()}})}function shouldHaveHeading(e){var a=!1,r=e.body_markdown.split("\n");try{a|=/^#/.test(e.body_markdown),a|=["-","="].indexOf(r[1][0])>-1,a&=LANGUAGE_REG.test(e.body_markdown)}catch(n){}return a}function shouldHaveScore(e){var a=!1;try{a|=SIZE_REG.test(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0])}catch(r){}return a}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){answers=answers.filter(shouldHaveScore).filter(shouldHaveHeading),answers.sort(function(e,a){var r=+(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG)||[1/0])[0],n=+(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG)||[1/0])[0];return r-n});var e={},a=1,r=null,n=1;answers.forEach(function(s){var t=s.body_markdown.split("\n")[0],o=jQuery("#answer-template").html(),l=(t.match(NUMBER_REG)[0],(t.match(SIZE_REG)||[0])[0]),c=t.match(LANGUAGE_REG)[1],i=getAuthorName(s);l!=r&&(n=a),r=l,++a,o=o.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",i).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",c).replace("{{SIZE}}",l).replace("{{LINK}}",s.share_link),o=jQuery(o),jQuery("#answers").append(o),e[c]=e[c]||{lang:c,user:i,size:l,link:s.share_link}});var s=[];for(var t in e)e.hasOwnProperty(t)&&s.push(e[t]);s.sort(function(e,a){return e.lang>a.lang?1:e.lang<a.lang?-1:0});for(var o=0;o<s.length;++o){var l=jQuery("#language-template").html(),t=s[o];l=l.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",t.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",t.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",t.size).replace("{{LINK}}",t.link),l=jQuery(l),jQuery("#languages").append(l)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",answers=[],page=1;getAnswers();var SIZE_REG=/\d+(?=[^\d&]*(?:&lt;(?:s&gt;[^&]*&lt;\/s&gt;|[^&]+&gt;)[^\d&]*)*$)/,NUMBER_REG=/\d+/,LANGUAGE_REG=/^#*\s*([^,]+)/;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table></div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table></div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody></table><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## K, 20

```
{y#y#'"|-"8 8#0b\:x}
```

.

```
             0b\:x    // convert to binary
         8 8#         // reshape into an 8x8 boolean matrix
     "|-"             // index into this char vector using the booleans as indices  
  y#'                 // extend horizontally
y#                    // extend vertically
```

.

```
k){y#y#'"|-"8 8#0b\:x}[3703872701923249305j;10]
"||--||--||"
"|--||--||-"
"--||--||--"
"-||--||--|"
"||--||--||"
"|--||--||-"
"--||--||--"
"-||--||--|"
"||--||--||"
"|--||--||-"

k){y#y#'"|-"8 8#0b\:x}[3703872701923249305j;8]
"||--||--"
"|--||--|"
"--||--||"
"-||--||-"
"||--||--"
"|--||--|"
"--||--||"
"-||--||-"
```

Comment: It really doesn't get simpler or more straightforward than this!

Comment: @JohnE That's only true for people who understand K. ;)

Answer (score 13):

## CJam, <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
q~:X;2b64Te["|-"f=8/{X*X<z}2*N*
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%3AX%3B2b64Te%5B%22%7C-%22f%3D8%2F%7BX*X%3Cz%7D2*N*&input=3732582711467756595%2023)

### Explanation

```
q~      e# Read and eval input.
:X;     e# Store the side length in X and discard it.
2b      e# Convert to base 2.
64Te[   e# Left-pad to length 64 with zeroes.
"|-"f=  e# Select '|' for 0 and '=' for 1.
8/      e# Split into chunks of 8 bits.
{       e# Do the following twice:
  X*    e#   Repeat lines X times (to ensure we have enough of them).
  X<    e#   Truncate them to exactly X lines.
  z     e#   Transpose the grid.
        e#   The transpose ensures that the second pass tiles the columns, and that the
        e#   grid is oriented correctly again after both passes are done.
}2*
N*      e# Join lines by newline characters.
```

Comment: I applaud you :). This is probably the quickest answer in PPCG history

Comment: @BetaDecay The benefit of golfing languages is that you have less to type, so you can code faster. :P

Comment: Geez, even went to the trouble of editing the tags *before* answering! Somebody spends too much time golfing ;P

Comment: Is this intended output: [link](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%3AX%3B2b64Te%5B%22%7C-%22f%3D8%2F%7BX*X%3Cz%7D2*N*&input=2123123123123123232334%2050%0A)

Comment: @Kenzie that input number is bigger than `2^64-1`.

Answer (score 5):

## Java, <s>110</s> <s>109</s>  107 Bytes

My code is in the form of an anonymous lambda function that takes a `long` and an `int` then returns a `String`.

```java
(w,s)->{String b="";for(int j,i=s--;i-->0;b+='\n')for(j=s;j>=0;)b+=(w>>8*(i%8)+j--%8)%2<1?'|':45;return b;}
```

Complete testable class

```java
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
public class AsciiWeave {   
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BiFunction<Long,Integer,String> weave = 
            (w,s)->{String b="";for(int j,i=s--;i-->0;b+='\n')for(j=s;j>=0;)b+=(w>>8*(i%8)+j--%8)%2<1?'|':45;return b;}}
        ;
        System.out.println(weave.apply(Long.valueOf(args[0]),Integer.valueOf(args[1])));
    }
}
```

Comment: I must say, I'm not used to being beaten by Java. :P Nice work.

Comment: Thanks @AlexA.! Lambdas really make java more usable for golfing: `(w,s)->` instead of `String w(long w,int s)` is a big save right off the bat.

Comment: @Ypnypn that should definitely work

Comment: Wow, this is impressive. Good job.

Comment: [105 bytes](https://tio.run/##VY9fa8IwFMXf/RQXQZrMttRWsS62gz0MBht78NH5kGos6WpSkrQinZ@9S/2zscBNLuccbn63oA31ZMVEsfvq@KGSykBhNb82vPT3tdgaLoX/zF9uLRlUdVbyLWxLqjW8Uy6gBYCBLbhZ2lBjn0byHRxsAK2M4iJfb4CqXOP2ku3P39jlmxS5@yoMy5lyr/kUjow2DBLo0NHV2EvbqwFZMhySvVSIC4vr8kQT7nlpQLJx4nwKB/deYVXPK9IkINjq6Jim8QPioxiPC3uNwuXkyfl2HqczopiplYCMnLs7GvmFXJ20YQdf1sav7O@mFOjC5dOqKk@oB/cbWtbsY4/6/dbBBt83@W9MNhjj6@Dz4Nx10TyI4nk4DyaLMAqniyiYdfEP "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## Matlab, <s>86</s> 80 bytes

```matlab
function f(W,S)
a='|-';x=de2bi(typecast(W,'uint8'))+1;s=8-mod(0:S-1,8);a(x(s,s))
```

Thanks to Hoki for his suggestion, which led me to save me 6 bytes.

Example:

```matlab
>> W = uint64(3732582711467756595)
W =
  3732582711467756595
>> S = uint8(10)
S =
   10
>> f(W,S)
ans =
||--||--||
--||--||--
--||--||--
||--||--||
||--||--||
--||--||--
--||--||--
||--||--||
||--||--||
--||--||--
```

Comment: `de2bi` will save you a few more characters ;-)

Comment: @Hoki! Thanks! I thought about it... but it gives a different order of the result

Comment: yep, you have to reverse `a='|-'` to `a='-|'`. And use `x=de2bi(typecast(W,'uint8'))+1;`

Comment: @Hoki I managed to fit `de2bi` just moving the `9-` term (used for reversal). Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

## J, 28 bytes

```
'|-'{~]$"1]$8 8$_64{.#.inv@[
```

Usage:

```
   3732582711467756595 ('|-'{~]$"1]$8 8$_64{.#.inv@[) 10
||--||--||
--||--||--
--||--||--
||--||--||
||--||--||
--||--||--
--||--||--
||--||--||
||--||--||
--||--||--
```

Explanation (right to left):

```
#.inv@[   binary representation vector of S
_64{.     padded with 0-s from the right to length 64
8 8$      reshaped in an 8 by 8 matrix
]$"1]$    tiled to a W by W size
'|-'{~    select | or - based on matrix element values
```

[Try it online here.](http://tryj.tk/)

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 145 bytes

```julia
f(w,s)=(A=map(i->i=="1"?"-":"|",reshape(split(lpad(bin(w),64,0),""),8,8))';for i=1:s A=hcat(A,A)end;for i=1:s println(join(A[i>8?i%8:i,1:s]))end)
```

This creates a function that accepts two integers and prints to stdout.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```julia
function f(w,s)
    # Convert w to binary, left-padded with zeros to length 64
    b = lpad(bin(w), 64, 0)

    # Create an 8x8 array of | and -
    A = transpose(map(i -> i == "1" ? "-" : "|", reshape(split(b, ""), 8, 8)))

    # Horizontally concatenate A to itself s times
    for i = 1:s
        A = hcat(A, A)
    end

    # Print the rows of A, recycling as necessary
    for i = 1:s
        println(join(A[i > 8 ? i % 8 : i, 1:s]))
    end
end
```

This is pretty long and I'm sure it can be made much shorter. Working on it.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>30</s> <s>28</s> 27 bytes

```
q~_2m*W%/ff{8f%8bm>"|-"=}N*
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~_2m*W%25%2Fff%7B8f%258bm%3E%22%7C-%22%3D%7DN*&input=3732582711467756595%2010).

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 77

```python
lambda w,s:''.join('|-'[w>>~n/s%8*8+~n%s%8&1]+'\n'[~n%s:]for n in range(s*s))
```

For each of the `s*s` values of `n`:

- Compute the coordinates via divmod `(i,j)=(n/s,n%s)`
- Compute the location in the tiling as `(i%8,j%8)`
- Compute the appropriate bit position as `8*(i%8)+(j%8)`
- Extract that bit of `w` by shifting `w` that many spaces with right and take the last bit with `&1`.
- Join one of '|-' at that position
- Add the newline at the end of every row whenever `n%s==0`

Actually, all that ends up getting the tiling backwards, since it reads `w` from the end. We fix this by using `~n` in place of `n`. I tried a recursive approach instead, but it turned out slightly longer.

The expression `w>>~n/s%8*8+~n%s%8&1` is a miracle of operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

## C, <strike>160</strike> 135 bytes

```
i;main(s,v)char**v;{s=atoi(v[2]);for(;i++<s*s+s;)putchar(i%(s+1)?strtoull(v[1],0,10)&1ull<<63-(i/(s+1)*8+(i%(s+1)-1)%8)%64?45:'|':10);}
```

Some more golfing can be done here and need an explanation, but I don't have time at the moment :)

### Ungolfed:

```
i;

main(s,v)
char**v;
{
    s=atoi(v[2]);
    for(;i++<s*s+s;)
        putchar(i%(s+1) ? /* print dash or pipe, unless at end of row, then print newline */
            /* Calculating which bit to check based on the position is the tough part */
            strtoull(v[1],0,10) & 1ull << 63-(i/(s+1)*8+(i%(s+1)-1)%8)%64 ? /* If bit at correct index is set, print dash, otherwise pipe */
                45 /* dash */
                : '|' /* pipe */
            : 10); /* newline */
}
```

Comment: Could you format the title like "C, 100 bytes"? That way it'll show up in the leaderboard better.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting your code to run correctly on my environment. Are you compiling with any specific options?

Comment: @dohaqatar7 It looks like some Linux environments require `stdlib.h` to be included explicitly. I wasn't forced to include it earlier when I tested on CentOS (I believe that's what I was on). Now on Ubuntu, I can't get it to run without compiling like so: `gcc -include stdlib.h w.c`

Comment: Makes sense I tested on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 132 Bytes

Certainly not the most elegant solution, and it's barely shorter than C, but it's a start.. Input is taken comma-separated.

```py
k,n=input()
k=[`['|-'[int(x)]for x in'{0:064b}'.format(k)]`[2::5][i*8:i*8+8]*n for i in range(8)]*n
for j in range(n):print k[j][:n]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```
L<*QbQjbyyMcs@L"|-".[Z64jvz2 8
```

The input should be on two lines, ***W*** then ***S***.

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=L%3C*QbQjbyyMcs%40L%22%7C-%22.%5BZ64jvz2+8&input=3732582711467756595%0A10&debug=0)

### Explanation

```
L                              # define y(b):
  *Qb                          #   b, repeated Q (the second input) times
 <   Q                         #   cut to length Q

                        jvz2   # convert the first input to binary
                   .[Z64       # pad with 0's to length 64
             @L"|-"            # map the digits to the appropriate character
            s                  # convert the list of characters to a string
           c                 8 # chop into 8 strings
         yM                    # extend each string to the correct size
        y                      # extend the list of strings to the correct size
      jb                       # join with newlines
```